# What happens to Ether in a smart contract after selfdestruct

Tags: ethereum, solidity

When calling `selfdestruct` on a Smart contract, what happens to the Ether inside of the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selfdestruct` takes one argument an `address` and then sends all the Ether in the contract to that `adrress`.